# It's a good pattern to put function in a ReactJS state?

Tags: reactjs

I don't feel right to store a function in a reactjs state, but not sure any disadvantage? Could anyone help analyze it?

```js
view1: function() {
  return <div>view1</view>
}

view2: fucntion() {
  return <div>view2</view>
}

goView1: function() {
  this.setState({contentView: view1})
}

goView2: function() {
  this.setState({contentView: view2})
}

render: function () {
  return(
    {this.state.contentView()}
  )
}
```

Comment: For one, it may cause unintentional re-renders when state change is simply changing a function?

Comment: why would you ever need to keep a function in state, anything that doesn't change/ its doesn't doesn't effect the render shouldn't be in state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few common gotchas about state in react:

- Don't mutate state directly, use `setState` instead
- Don't use state when not referenced in render, use instance variable instead.

Well, it seems fine to use state as function, since it's used in your render function to return what to render? Alright, it might not be an anti-pattern, but a better place to put those functions might be in your **props**, aka [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), a few reasons:

- Think state as your component's data model.

  Data are not stale, it **changes** over time, it could be results from async operations, ui states after user interactions, controlled forms values etc. 
  Just like redux stores your app's global state, react state should store your component's local state that changes over time, while functions most of time, does nothing more than deferring execution.
- Render props is different, it offers IoC (Inversion of Control) for free.

  Props most of time similar to local state, should be concerned with UI rendering. However, unlike state owned/managed by component itself, props are passed from parents/clients of the component.

  Event handlers for example, event target (usually DOM elements like button, input etc) doesn't need to know how to handle events when creating the component, instead it yields control back to component client/consumer who might need to use `setState` in its `handleEventName` handler to update certain container's state shared across children.

  Some library (e.g., react router4) also shifted from HOC to render props (e.g., react 16.3 new context API - provider/consumer pair) in favor of its flexibility and explicitness. Instead of composing HOCs before runtime for static version of final enhanced component, you can declare what to render  using render props and composing them at runtime in render functions. Thus, you get a clear separation between data (state/props) provider and consumer (where render props are passed from).

Regarding any performance (re-render) concerns, i think it's totally fine to use state as function, since most performance tricks are done by using `shouldComponentUpdate` hook with shallow compare state/props references (e.g. React.PureComponent, Redux Connect etc), so it's where immutability and memoization comes into play.